# Siddhi how do yo pause streaming after a number of events is met and resume streaming

Tags: siddhi

From FirstInputStream#window.timeBatch(1 min)
select a, b, c, count() as ev_count
insert into Second InputStream
having ev_count > 2;

How do you pause for three hours after event count is met?
I want to stop reading more events after the event count is met?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this [1] Rate limiting example? It looks like your use case aligns with the example.

[1] https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/examples/time-rate-limit/